# WebApi - adding remote forms authentication cookie to bearer token - and serving token back to Angular client

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, token

I have the following sites: asp.net MVC site with Angular (1) -> WebApi (2) -> asp.net MVC remote site with a mix of WCF and MVC services (3)

(1) The Angular client runs in a new "lighter" asp .net MVC site, and should use a bearer token to get data from the WebApi. Future requirments: Single-sign-on

(2) The WebApi will be the future endpoint. But as of now, a heavy backend from the old site (3), requires a temporary solution. The heavy backend will gradualy be moved to the WebApi, leaving out such as silverlight components, windows application dependencies, etc, etc. The WebApi is also a new setup, but serves tokens via the /token endpoint. I followed this guide: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

(3) The remote asp.net MVC site contains a bunch of WCF services and a few MVC Controllers serving as api's. The WCF services allow HTTP json etc using WebInvoke. It requires session and forms authentication. It responds with a cookie.

My question is. How can I use the WebApi as a middle layer between new MVC site (1) and old MVC site (3), using HttpClient in the WebApi controller action method? I assume I will need to pick up the cookie from old site (3), add it to the token as custom properties or claims..? Return the token to the new site (1), and let Angular save the token to local storage in the browser.. Angular will then send the token on every request to WebApi (2) that requires authorization. Then the WebApi controller action method (2), will unwrap the custom data from the token (the cookie), and send this to the old site (3) upon requests..

Answer (score 0):

I thinks cookies form one site can't consume in anther site.
If you have access to site3 users database:
1-Have a token endpoint in the site1 that validdate the user and return a token .
2-Call token endpoint from site1(client side ) and get a token.
3-Add token to any request with Authorization Bearer header.
Hope this help

Comment: First of all, I have only access to site3 wcf and mvc api's, which both require cookies (no access to users). I have access to a LoginController in site3, where I can get a valid cookie from. Site1 doesn't need to care about this cookie, if it is encapsulated inside the token, by some service inbetween.. So how do I do this?